# Square Payments : International

Tags: square-connect, square

I am trying to get some clarification on Square Payments and International Cards.  I am setting up a payment processor for a site which will need to allow Credit cards from all over - not just US/CANADA.  It looks like Square is only available for US,CANADA,AUSTRALIA,UK,JAPAN - can anyone confirm if this is correct?

The method I'll be using is the web form.  User will enter their info into the form and submit, back end will process the transaction using the Square SDK (PHP).

If Square is not capable of processing in other countries, is it possible (and not violation of PCI compliance rules) for me to take the CC info from the user, submit to PHP script which will process it using cURL request that way the IP processing the payment is our host server in US?  Would that allow me to get around the Country limitation?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://stripe.com/global may be a better option. Processing the CC info on your server would incur full PCI compliance (expensive and time consuming) and likely not help anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square requires the seller/merchant account to be created in one of the supported countries (US, UK, Canada, Australia, Japan), but once that account is set up you can accept payments online via the APIs from any country (as long as it's a [supported card](https://squareup.com/help/us/en/article/5085-accepted-cards) of course). Note that the payment *must* be in the currency of the Square account though (USD for US-based account, for example), and the customer's bank would handle the currency exchange if they use a different currency.